# P2118 Motor Current Range/Performance

Tags: toyota, cel, camry, fuse

We were trying to solve an issue with the taillight on our 2004 Toyota Camry when we saw the check engine light come on.  I checked the code and it was P2118.

A little backstory: when checking the problem with the taillight, we thought maybe there was a fuse for it and it was blown, so my wife checked a bunch but no issues found.  After that, the check engine light was coming on.

Would that really be triggered by a fuse, or is this coincidental?  I'm a newbie when it comes to figuring out these problems...

Comment: Was the ignition on when you were checking the fuses? You should recheck any fuses you pulled to make sure they're in all the way. If those are OK reset the code and see if it comes back.

Comment: The ignition was not on.  I was fairly confident they were all pressed in, but I'll double-check.  Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

That code refers to the Electronic Throttle Body not receiving power. I recommend checking/replacing the ETCS fuse in the underhood fuse box.